# How to access external library from docker container?

Tags: docker, ocr, tesseract, apache-tika, docker-container

I wrote an API using Apache Tika with spring-boot, and I ran this application in docker as a container, but Apache Tika depends on Tesseract-OCR, which is installed on the host machine. Is there any method that the container can access Tesseract-OCR?

When I ran this spring-boot application directly on the host machine, Apache Tika invoked Tesseract-OCR successfully.

Env:
    Ubuntu 16.04
    Java 8

Core Code:

```
    InputStream input = file.getInputStream();
    BodyContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    metadata.set(TikaMetadataKeys.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, file.getOriginalFilename());

    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
    context.set(Parser.class, parser);
    parser.parse(input, textHandler, metadata, context);
```

Comment: Why not add Tesseract to your container as well? That way, it'll work no matter where you deploy the container to. It's the container way!

Comment: ...or keep both services separate, each in its own docker container and work with `docker-compose`. (It think this is considered best practice, see [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container))